# Intervention study design

Tags: methodology, clinical-trials

I am facing the following "problem": I want to evaluate the effects of an intervention on certain outcomes in a group of adolescents athletes. Obviously the best choice would be to conduct a randomized controlled trial. However, I *won't* get the coaches to perform the intervention with only half of their teams.

The next best choice imo would be to conduct a non-randomized trial, e.g. two teams with only one performing the intervention. However, I fear that the effect due to coach/team is greater than that of the intervention. Or said differently I fear that at baseline the teams are already "different" and thereby comparing them is not valid.

Therefore I came up with the following design. Athletes are measured three times. Between measurement 1 and 2 they perform their usual training without intervention. Between measurement 2 and 3 they do perform the additional intevention. Then I would compare the differences between 1&2 and 2&3. If the letter are greater the intervention has an effect.

**First Question: Is there a name for such a design?**

**Second question: Can I make causal conclusion about the effect of the intervention based on this design?**

I am quite unsure about this because there will also be changes due to the normal training and growth between measurement 1 and 2.